# Woocommerce Related Products only showing the same products on reload

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce version 2.3.10
Wordpress 4.2.2

The related products are cycling through the same products, which seem to be the first few products added to the shop.

It displays them in random order, but doesn't randomly show all of the products in the category.

I've read that this could be due to a plugin conflict preventing random products from being shown, but I haven't been able to find any conflict.

Comment: It could also be due to caching. [`$product->get_related()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1237) does cache the results, so on page load the items would not randomize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I've cleared my browser cache and reloaded, that didn't do it. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the products are cached in a transient and have nothing to do with your browser cache. You can clear the transients in the WooCommerce settings, but it still won't change with each page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Get the same problem here. Find something that worked: in related.php is like that:

```
$related = $product->get_related( '$posts_per_page' );
```

I changed the value "$posts_per_page" to "99", like this:

```
$related = $product->get_related( '99' );
```

So this worked! I was suspecting that the woo gets only the X number of products from the related and because of that was cycling through them (here was 4 products). Obviously the problem is in the value this variable gets, but for now i will leave like this.